# Mapping one-to-one relationship + Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have a database with a table `users` with fields: `user_id, username, password`, ... . I also have a table `players` with `player_name, player_position`, ... AND a FK `user_id`.
Image relationship:
[image]

I genered the entities from the database but now I would like to get the player from user like this $user->getPlayer(). And doctrine didn't generate player in Users entity, only user in Players Entity.

This is what I have now:

```
    /**
 * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="userId")
 */
private $player;

/**
 * Get player
 *
 * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
 */

public function getPlayer() {
    return $this->player;
}
/**
 * Set player
 *
 * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player
 * @return Users
 */
public function setPlayer(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player = null){
    $this->player = $player;

    return $this;
}
```

But when I try $user->getPlayer() I always get null. (And the user_id is in players table)

**UPDATE:**
My Players Entity:

```
<?php

namespace VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Players
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="players", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_players_users1_idx", columns={"user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_players_teams1_idx", columns={"team_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_players_myteam1_idx", columns={"myteam_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Players
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_licensenumber", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerLicensenumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_position", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerPosition;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_birthyear", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $playerBirthyear;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $playerId;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="myteam_id", referencedColumnName="myteam_id")
     * })
     */
    private $myteam;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="team_id")
     * })
     */
    private $team;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;



    /**
     * Set playerName
     *
     * @param string $playerName
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerName($playerName)
    {
        $this->playerName = $playerName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerName()
    {
        return $this->playerName;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerLicensenumber
     *
     * @param string $playerLicensenumber
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerLicensenumber($playerLicensenumber)
    {
        $this->playerLicensenumber = $playerLicensenumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerLicensenumber
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerLicensenumber()
    {
        return $this->playerLicensenumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerPosition
     *
     * @param string $playerPosition
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerPosition($playerPosition)
    {
        $this->playerPosition = $playerPosition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerPosition
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerPosition()
    {
        return $this->playerPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerBirthyear
     *
     * @param integer $playerBirthyear
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerBirthyear($playerBirthyear)
    {
        $this->playerBirthyear = $playerBirthyear;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerBirthyear
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPlayerBirthyear()
    {
        return $this->playerBirthyear;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPlayerId()
    {
        return $this->playerId;
    }

    /**
     * Set myteam
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam $myteam
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setMyteam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam $myteam = null)
    {
        $this->myteam = $myteam;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get myteam
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam 
     */
    public function getMyteam()
    {
        return $this->myteam;
    }

    /**
     * Set team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team = null)
    {
        $this->team = $team;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get team
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams 
     */
    public function getTeam()
    {
        return $this->team;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users $user
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setUser(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: In my Users Entity Class I have now:

```
 /**
 * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 * })
 */
private $player;
```

But it still doesn't work ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your annotations are not set correctly (specifically, the JoinColumn).  It is interesting that you aren't getting an error, but anyways... replace this:

```
/**
 * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="userId")
 */
private $player;
```

with this:

```
/**
 * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 */
private $player;
```

notice that your `referencedColumnName` should be the name as it is shown in the database, not the Doxtrine entity.  Start by fixing those errors, and it should solve the problem.

**UPDATE**

This is a very different setup it you want a `manyToOne` relationship.

```
/**
 * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Players", mappedBy="user_id")
 */
private $players;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->players = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Because `$players` can now have many values, it should be set as an `ArrayCollection`.  I also made the variable `$players` instead of `$player`, for ease of readability.

You should really familiarize yourself with the Symfony Docs, this is a very simple problem that is described very clear in the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata)

Comment: It doesn't work. But my auto-generated players entity shows a many to one relation to users table. I updated my begin post with the Players entity. What should I post as annotation in my users table now?

Comment: I updated my begin post to manytoOne, but it still doesn't work. Could you take a look at it?